# Can I open Byte array of Docx/Pdf file to WebView in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

1. I get byte array data from specified API, and I want to show it on web view in my application.
2. Is there any option to open word file in Windows Phone with web view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't show those files in a WebView inside your application. The regular way to show those files by storing them in a file and invoking LaunchFileAsync() to hand displaying off to the system. If only one App supports the file type it will launch directly - otherwise the user will be prompted which App he wants to use to see them.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701465.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for more information